# Are you interested in writing for the Blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

You have to go back 13 entries on the [blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1) to find something that wasn't written by me. I'd really like to see more participation from users submitting stuff for the blog.

Some ideas (but not limited to):

- Movies Reviews
- TV Shows or Genres
- Books
- Conventions
- Comics
- Shark vs Gorilla (write an imaginary match up between two characters)

For instance, Captain America: The Winter Soldier is coming out soon. If someone were to see that opening weekend and write their thoughts about it, that would be great.

A lot of stuff on the blog right now is reviews (mostly my fault), but if you want to write comparisons, ideas, ways to improve, submit your own short story (FanFics are not necessarily allowed) all would be welcome. Do you feel Scifi.SE is too science fiction focused and forgets the Fantasy? Write about it, or offer suggestions for reading / watching of your favorite Fantasy series and why.

Some people may feel they are under-qualified to submit a post. All it takes it just putting your thoughts into words. I'm happy to copy edit if you worry about grammar and spelling. I'm also happy to offer suggestions.

Comment: How sciency can it get and how fictiony does it have to be?

Comment: @bitmask What did you have in mind? I'm pretty open.

Comment: I suspect I currently don't have the time to do it proper justice, but I was considering compiling some real-world scientific results about things that were predicted by sci-fi.

Comment: @bitmask That is what I thought it might be about. I am perfectly fine with "scifi tech / theories that turned into real life" kind of stuff.

Comment: Would articles like the one in my answer to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10759/does-the-ending-of-tau-zero-make-sense be appropriate?

Comment: @JohnRennie You are taking something from scifi and saying it is not possible (based on our current understanding), whereas bitmask was taking something from scifi that proved to be right. I think that approach is going to be more interesting to a scifi group at large than debunking scifi claims. That being said, do you have other examples that you think might make good articles?

Comment: I'm currently [reviewing Sandman: Overture](http://magnificentnose.com/tag/sandman-overture/) as the issues come out. Would the scifi.SE blog be interested posting excerpts of these? Say, use the first paragraph as a teaser, with a link?

Comment: I would be very interested in writing film or book reviews - I used to write film reviews as a way of paying for university, matter of fact - but I can't commit to anything regular right now; I have a toddler, a job, am continuing my studies and have a very cranky wife who will no doubt punch me since she's reading as I type this. But I'd be interested in reviewing the upcoming *X-Men* film, maybe *Winter Soldier* - though I may not get to see it - and I can offer reviews of old science fiction novels, books and films.

Comment: @JamesSheridan That would be great. Whatever you can contribute would be appreciated.

Comment: @neilfein I think that would be okay, as long as you recognize that anything submitted on the stackexchange network falls under their creative commons license.

Comment: hi JBN nice work on the community blog & esp appreciate offer to copy edit. wondering, do you have any access to hit statistics? what kind of traffic does the blog get? divulged exposure info could be some incentive... anyway, recently wrote up this post [15yr matrix anniversary links](http://vzn1.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/matrix-15-year-anniversary-still-subversive-as-ever/) on my own blog, what do you think? "good enough"?

Comment: @Vzn that article would have been a nice addition for the blog. I like the comic too. In terms of statistics, because we typically only see one new post per month we typically only see a couple of thousand visitors per month. I believe more content and more writers is the solution to improved statistics.

Comment: JBN thx for interest; am ok with you republishing the article in scifi blog if its acceptable. plz invite me to chat room if further attn is reqd.

Comment: @Vzn you will need to request an account to the blog via a moderator.

Comment: can it be a guest post entered by you, credited to me to start? dont have other ideas/other blogs at moment